# Is there an example of a non compact, semisimple, amenable Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions, amenability

By semisimple I mean the real Lie algebra of $G$ is semisimple. I guess there is not but I can't formulate a rigorous argument.

Comment: I just read here:

 http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/talks/NormalSubgroups-Lecture1-Chgo-2-08.pdf

that if G is connected, then its amenable iff it has a closed normal solvable subgroup, N, such that G/N is compact.  But semisimple groups have no nontrivial connected normal solvable subgroups.   Not sure if discrete N are an issue or not...

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a noncompact semisimple Lie group. If $G$ is connected, then it contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{F}_2$, the free group with 2 generators (see [Theorem 3.9](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CA4aBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA107) in the book by Patterson), thus not amenable.

If $G$ is not connected, then let $G_e$ be the connected component of identity. $G_e$ [is an open subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184104/lie-groups-identity-component), so the factor group $G/G_e$
is discrete. $G$ is amenable iff both $G_e$ and $G/G_e$ are amenable. By definition, $G$ and $G_e$ has the same solvable radical (i.e., the largest solvable connected closed normal subgroup), so $G_e$ is also semisimple. Thus, the connected semisimple Lie group $G_e$ is amenable iff $G_e$ is compact. In summary, if $G$ is not connected, then $G$ is amenable iff $G_e$ is compact and $G/G_e$ is an amenable discrete group.

To find an example of a non-connected non-compact semisimple Lie group, take a compact semisimple Lie group $H$ and an infinite amenable discrete group $D$, and define the cartesian product $G=H\times D$.